# how to pass string data from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to pass string value from activity to fragment. For that I'm using bundle for transferring string value.

**PUT STRING ACTIVITY**
Passing string value :-

```
           Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Value", resultp.get(CurrentProjectActivity.VALUE));
            Log.d(TAG, "Value  ::: " + resultp.get(CurrentProjectActivity.VALUE));
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            AmenetiesFragment fragobj = new AmenetiesFragment();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

In log I got "Value" value as well.

GET STRING VALUE IN FRAGMENT (IT IS NOT WORKING).

```
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    Log.d(TAG, "Value's value:)  ::: " + bundle);
    String strtext = bundle.getString("Value");
    return rootView;
}
```

In log I'm getting NULL value for BUNDLE. Please help me to resolve this Issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you create and set arguments to fragment?

Comment: "Value" is Sting that I pick from JSON using JSON parsing technique. From that I can get value as well. In log I can view that.

Comment: @Amar probably resultp.get(CurrentProjectActivity.VALUE) is not type String.check another way my answer.

Answer (score 11):

I advice you to follow this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949746/how-to-send-data-from-activity-to-fragment) . You should use interface. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in the Frament task

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: These links are really good. I used first link few days before.

Comment: @Paritosh So whats the problem. Thats the std way we use it

Comment: Ya. I'm using Sliding menu as Interface for this.

Comment: @Amar Did it worked now. Please double check the value

Comment: @james. Its not working. for Sliding menu I'm implementing this concept. So I create fragment In SlidingActivity Also. that maybe the reason. I'll check and update. Thanks:)

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to send String data from Activity to Fragment

In Fragment.java file add the following code,

```
public static String name= null;

public void setName(String string){
name = string;
}
```

In MainActivity.java from which you want to send String add the following code,

```
String stringYouWantToSend;

Fragment fragment =  new Fragment();
fragment.setName(stringYouWantToSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

make public first in activity that object you required in fragment.
then you can use like `((ACtivityName)getActivity()).objectName;`
i hope it help.this is not best way to pass data into fragment.

there are some other way also.
create constructor of your fragment class and pass it and save in fragment like:

```
    public MyFragment(String data){
       this.data = data;
    }
```

also you can use as bundle @james answer.

EDIT:-

**First Way**

```
private class MyFeagment extends Fragment {
    private String data;
    private Object myObject;

    public MyFeagment(String data, Object anyObject) {
        this.data = data;
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("My Fragment", "data :: " + data + " and myObject :"
                + myObject);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

let's say it is your framgnet.
and put this code in your activity

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new MyFeagment("My Data",
            "data"));
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I didn't get ur way. I think u r trying to get the data the same way we use in onAttach

Comment: thanks man. perfect. Cleary understood what u wanna say. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The savedInstance variable will be empty the first time you run your app, 
it only gets filled when the onSaveInstanceState method is called, this usually happens when you rotate the screen, then savedInstance variable will be populated. Try this :

```
if(savedInstance != null){
  Log.d(TAG, "There's is something");
}else{
  Log.d(TAG, "Nothing in there");
}
```

First time in logcat you will see the first message, try turning your device and the message in the else will show.

As @james said, the recommended way is to use interfaces, or have a field class but this increases coupling and destroys the whole point of fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Approach but not Recommended

You can access activity data from fragment:

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private String myString = "hello";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        ...
    }

    public String getMyData() {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
        String myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
        return view;
    }
}
```