# How to pass data from activity to fragment?

Tags: android-studio

I'm creating a basic app and i stucked at this point where I'm unable to pass data from an activity to fragment.

**EmailPage.java**

```
 public class EmailPage extends AppCompatActivity{

        ImageButton btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_emailpage);


            btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.emailButton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(EmailPage.this, YourName.class);

                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                }
            });

        }



    }
```

[Email Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjzn0.png)

**NavHeaderMainMenu1.java**

```
public class NavHeaderMainMenu1 extends Fragment {

    public NavHeaderMainMenu1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main_menu1, container , false);
    }

}
```

[NavHeaderMainMenu1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us0Zs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from Activity to Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949746/how-to-send-data-from-activity-to-fragment)

Comment: I also go through with this but nothing helped me out.